# How to pass a double quoted value of a variable, as argument of the curl command, in a bash script?

Tags: bash, curl, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have a script on a server whose last line is an echo which prints the value 
of an URL something like this:

```
.
.     < the script code here >
.
echo "url"      # The last line of this script
```

I don't have the possibility of changing this script and I can just 
capture its return value, that is, capture the url as the return value 
inside a variable declared in my local bash script, something like this:

```
cmd_url=$(ssh . . . <distinct script>)
```

Here is an example of such URL (for confidentiality reasons, of course 
I changed the values)

```
http://mydomain:56789/cgi-bin/WebObjects/JavaMonitor.woa/admin/running?type=app&name=AppTest&pw=abcd&9e0Xy
```

The above example is principally a WebObjects application info URL, which can be passed as an 
argument of the curl command in order to know whether an application 
is running (so the application name in this example is **AppTest** and the JavaMonitor 
password that I have to provide in order to be able to query is **abcd&9e0Xy**)

If I open a terminal, I can simply paste this url **enclosed within single quotes** and 
run the following

```
curl -s -X GET 'http://mydomain:56789/cgi-bin/WebObjects/JavaMonitor.woa/admin/running?type=app&name=AppTest&pw=abcd9e0Xy'
```

So I have to enclose the string within single quotes to escape special characters and that works pretty well, if the application AppTest is actually running then curl returns **YES**.

Now what I need to do, is to do exactly what I wrote above except that it is done inside 
a bash script and the url is not written manually enclosed within single quotes but 
it is stored inside a variable.

Here is what I do:

```
cmd_url=$(ssh . . . <distant script>)
ret_msg=$(curl -s -X GET "$cmd_url")
```

And the problem is (I presume) due to the special characters in the URL. It seems that curl fails to 
interpret the argument correctly. I even removed double quotes but that didn't
solve the problem either.

So my question is: how should I proceed ? How can I convert **an already double quoted** string 
(recall that this is done on the distant server & I cannot change that) to
a single quoted string? So that curl would take it just as a sequence of characters 
without interpreting them? like what I wrote above in the terminal example:

```
'http://mydomain:56789/cgi-bin/WebObjects/JavaMonitor.woa/admin/running?type=app&name=AppTest&pw=abcd9e0Xy'
```

So far I've tried different combinations of possible concatenation with single quotes 
but the problem persists. Either curl doesn't return anything at all or I get an error message
indicating the password has not been provided.

Any idea? How can I pass an **already double quoted** local variable to curl in a bash script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see anything in that string (unless the actual password is different) that would be treated differently whether you single- or double-quoted it. What is the actual error or failure that you see? `ret_msg=$(curl -s -X GET "$cmd_url")` should work.

Comment: Can you clarify whether or not the other script actually prints the double-quotes as part of its output? (Note that `echo "url"` does not print the double-quotes -- the shell removes them before the string is passed to `echo`.) Also, are there any other funny characters in the script's output? Try `otherscript | cat -vet` to make nonprinting characters visible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [tr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) to translate the double-quote to single-quote

```
$ echo \"foo\" | tr '"' "'"
'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried with tr but again the very same problem persists.